# ng-repeat with ngResource for django rest framework api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngresource

I have a django app that sends the following data on filter

I am able to fetch the data in browser as validated from console. The code for the same is:

```
var apps = $resource("/applications/");
$scope.apps = apps.query();
var a = $scope.apps;
console.log(a);
```

The *console* output:

[image]

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Magilite"},{"id":2,"name":"Cocom"},{"id":3,"name":"Valizer"}]
```

Now the problem comes when i try to loop it like

```
<h1 ng-repeat="app in apps">
    app : {{ app.name }}
</h1>
```

I looked at a lot of resource examples but can't see to figure out where I am going wrong. I do get three h1 elements rendered but no name.

Comment: What prints in `console.log(a);`?

Comment: @developer033 just added output from console to the question

Comment: Well, it's correct..

Comment: @developer033 still no output :(

Comment: can there be something wrong with the way i am using ng-repeat ?

Comment: Can you post your complete view? Or provide a https://plnkr.co/edit/ with the relevant code?

Comment: sure will do give me a min

Comment: @developer033 here is the link https://plnkr.co/edit/aexeJwHXj7uPNVilGZCR?p=preview I can see the terminal output but it doesn't seem to load the template

Comment: seems to be resolved here .

Comment: Yes, it works there.

Comment: now see i used the actual url for the api. here is the link http://api.deltaforce.xyz/applications/

Comment: my bad finally got it. I was making the application in jekyll and it is rendering the angular tags in its processor. Nothing with the js .

Comment: @developer033 thanks for taking the time out and helping me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Pleasure to help you :)